# bootstrap multi select drop-down not listing appended values

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-multiselect

I am new to mvc and I am facing an issue regarding bootstrap multiselect drop down.
I my program i have to get some values according to the selections from another dropdown. So even though I was able to append those values to the bootstrap dropdown I am not able to see the appended values in it. I think the issue is because the li's are not getting updated . Please suggest solution for this.

```
 $('#companyList').change(function () {
        var cid = $('#companyList').val();
                    //$('#projectList').empty();
        //$("#projectList").append("<option value='" + 0 + "' >" + "select" + "</option>");
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetProject",
            data: { id: cid },
            success: function (data) {
               // alert("reached");
                $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
                    $("#projectList").append("<option value='" + optiondata.ProjectId + "'>" + optiondata.ProjectName + "</option>");
                })

            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Are you getting values in `optiondata` at `ajax success`?

Comment: Yes i am getting the values and I am also able to do further operations with select all option,but not able to see it in the drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code:

```
$('#companyList').change(function () {
    var cid = $('#companyList').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "GetProject",
        data: { id: cid },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, optiondata) {
                $("#projectList").append("<option value='" + optiondata.ProjectId + "'>" + optiondata.ProjectName + "</option>");
            });

            $('#projectList').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });

         }
    });
})
```

I only added this:

```
$('#projectList').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});
```

To you original ajax 'success' function.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9v1wrco/

Comment: Thank you for replayingAlready tried it but not working.I even tried $("#projectList").multiselect("rebuild");

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I edited the body of your ajax 'success' function.

Comment: I am getting $(...).multiselect is not a function, when ever I am using it inside ajax call, can you please tell me what is the real reason for it.

Comment: Please check another edit. Now it allows to add an option to existing options.
Are you sure the bootstrap multiselect .js is loaded?